# Princess Farida on Spoj

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

I stuck at a problem [SPOJ](https://www.spoj.com/problems/FARIDA/#).
I checked all the test cases passing all of them, but I am still getting "WA" on spoj.
I know it can be solved using dynamic programming, but I am practicing memoization.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
vector <int> dp(1000000);
long long int maxloot(vector<int> &loot, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return loot[0];
    if (n == 2)
        return max(loot[0], loot[1]);
    if (dp[n] != -1)
        return dp[n];
    long long int take = loot[n - 1] + maxloot(loot, n - 2);
    long long int leave = maxloot(loot, n - 1);
    return dp[n]= max(take, leave);

}
int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    int p = 1;
    while (t--) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        vector <int> loot;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int temp;
            cin >> temp;
            loot.push_back(temp);
        }
        dp.assign(1000000, -1);

        cout <<"Case "<<p<<": "<< maxloot(loot, n)<<endl;
        p++;
        dp.clear();


    }
}
```

Test case 1:

> 5
>
> 1 2 3 4 5

Test case 2:

> 1
>
> 10

output 1:

> 9

output 2:

> 10

Comment: if you are passing all the test cases but still get "wrong answer", you may have something wrong on the output format. Situations like that is just another reason why online judges are b******t

Comment: ah you mean you pass all the example test cases but not the hidden ones. In that case you have to run more test cases. Find the one that does not pass and then fix it

Comment: If you don't know the actual input, it's really impossible to properly [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: to my experience it is impossible to write code that will produce correct output for **all** input. Hence, unless you know what input causes wrong output you cannot fix it

Comment: once i was using `int * int` and storing the values in `long long` in that case int max value was 1000 000 which is sufficient for int, but int *int  overflowed before the result get stored in long long because cpu was doing all calculation in int and then it was storing in long long 
when i will add int and long long it might create some problems? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: well, this solution clearly won't work if there are 10^4 monsters and each holds 10^9 coins (which can happen by the rules), because your dp array holds only integer, which will be overflowed. Can't say if it is the reason for WA though.

Comment: Calculating in `long long int` is of limited use if you store the results in a `vector<int>`.

Comment: accepted thanx@grungegurunge

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong data type to store value in vector dp.
As the sum of coins can go up to (10^9*10^2=10^11) therefore int would not be able to store it .Try using long long int instead as it would not lead to overflow condition.

SAME CODE AS YOURS(using long long int got accepted):

USE: vector< long long int>dp(1000000)

ACCEPTED CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#define ull unsigned long long
using namespace std;
vector <long long int> dp(1000000);
long long int maxloot(vector<int> &loot, int n) {
if (n == 0)
    return 0;
if (n == 1)
    return loot[0];
if (n == 2)
    return max(loot[0], loot[1]);
if (dp[n] != -1)
    return dp[n];
long long int take = loot[n - 1] + maxloot(loot, n - 2);
long long int leave = maxloot(loot, n - 1);
return dp[n]= max(take, leave);

}
int main() {
int t;
cin >> t;
int p = 1;
while (t--) {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> loot;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        loot.push_back(temp);
    }
    dp.assign(1000000, -1);

    cout <<"Case "<<p<<": "<< maxloot(loot, n)<<endl;
    p++;
    dp.clear();


}
}
```